# JSF 2 invoke another bean in view and render their view

Tags: jsf-2, javabeans

Following Example:

i have got three Beans:

1. GeneralBean
2. SpecificBean1
3. SpecificBean2

The view of the GeneralBean consists of an accordion that represents a list.
Now i would like to invoke the SpecificBean1 if a condition matches:

```
<c:if test="${condition==true}">
  <ui:include src="SpecificBean1.xhtml" />
</c:if>
```

The above examples includes the view but does not invoke the bean in the background. Is it possible to achieve that? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

So found out:

```
<c:if test="${condition==true}">
   <ui:include src="/pages/SpecificBean1.xhtml">
      <ui:param name="speacificBean" value="#{SpecificBean1}"></ui:param>
   </ui:include>
</c:if>
```

*had a typo in the src path :/

to check this add a @PostConstruct annotated method containing a log-message to the specific bean.

```
 @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
       log("Bean Created/Initialized");
    }
```

Comment: Just delete the question. A typo/localized question is never useful to anyone else.